# static link ffmpeg to rust binary

Tags: c, rust, low-level

I use the library `fffmpeg_next` from crates.io/ffmpeg-next in my project,
which is a bindings to `ffmpeg`.
I compile it on `windows 11` with `msys2` `ucrt64` and `windows-gnu` compiler of rust.

I would like to statically link `ffmpeg` library along with all it's libraries so my final `exe` will not be dependent on DLLs related to ffmpeg.

Is that possible?

I tried to find ready to use static libraries of `ffmpeg` for `windows`, but didn't found even that.

[image]

Comment: Try enabling the `"build"` or `"static"` feature of ffmpeg_next (see its [feature flags](https://docs.rs/crate/ffmpeg-next/6.1.1/features)).

Comment: I added this flag and now looks like it's looking for static library but doesn't link it well.

I get many undefined reference errors like:
undefined reference to `sftp_attributes_free' (not sure how ssh related!)

 = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
= note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo

Comment: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\home\User\ruscribe\target\release\deps\libffmpeg_sys_next-c90b3fba183585f5.rlib(libssh.o):(.text.unlikely+0x6d5): undefined reference to `sftp_attributes_free
Also it calles to mingw32 and I use it in msys2 ucrt64